# how to prove that $\hat \sigma^2$ is a consistent for $\sigma^2$?

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, variance, proof

Consider a regression model $Y_n=X_n\beta +\varepsilon$, where $X_n$ is a $n \times p_n$ matrix, and $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon_1,...,\varepsilon_n)'$ consists of independent and identically distributed variables with $E(\varepsilon_1)=0$ and $Var(\varepsilon_1)=\sigma^2$. Suppose that $\varepsilon_1 \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and suppose that $\hat \sigma ^2$ is the estimator of $\sigma^2$. Let

$$\hat \sigma ^2=\frac{\left\|Y_n-X_n\hat\beta\right\|^2}{n-p_n}.$$

Then, $\hat \sigma^2$ consistent for $\sigma^2$.

I can prove that $\hat \sigma^2$ is unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$.

How can I continue to prove that $\hat \sigma^2$ consistent for $\sigma^2$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014094/how-to-prove-that-hat-sigma2-is-a-consistent-for-sigma2?noredirect=1#comment4176908_2014094

Comment: Yeah, I asked it on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
\begin{align*}
P(|\hat{\sigma}^2 - \sigma^2| > \epsilon) \le \frac{E[(\hat{\sigma}^2 - \sigma^2)^2]}{\epsilon^2}
\end{align*}
by Markov's/Chebyshev's inequality. Then take the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative hint:

\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{\sigma}^{2}=\frac{Y_n'(I-P_{X_n})Y_n}{n-p_n}=\frac{\varepsilon'(I-P_{X_n})\varepsilon}{n-p_n}.
\end{eqnarray}
So,
\begin{align}
\hat{\sigma}^{2}=\frac{\frac{\varepsilon'\varepsilon}{n}-\frac{\varepsilon'X_n}{n}\left(\frac{X_n'X_n}{n}\right)^{-1}\frac{X_n'\varepsilon}{n}}{\frac{n-p_n}{n}}.
\end{align}

This is a continuous function of three arguments
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{X_n'X_n}{n}&\to_p&?\\
\frac{\varepsilon'\varepsilon}{n}&=&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}\varepsilon_{t}^{2}\to_p?\\
\frac{X_n'\varepsilon}{n}&\to_p&?.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks a lot. For this method, $X_i$ is random variable, but for my case, $X_i$ is fixed. My supervisor asked me not to use this method. He told me to prove unbiased estimator and then continue to prove the lim of variance.